# How to fix overriding of default AccessDeniedHandler (AccessDeniedHandlerImpl) in Spring Security (Java) config?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, access-denied

I have a small *web application based on Spring MVC and Spring Security*. I have difficulties setting my own `AccessDeniedHandler` that should redirect unauthorized users to my custom error page.

I use `http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler)` in my config class that extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`. The default `AccessDeniedHandler` keeps being invoked despite the setting (I debugged `ExceptionTranslationFilter`). As a result the container-defined error page is displayed instead of my custom one.

Do you have an idea what I am missing here? What could be the issue? Thank you kindly for your help.

An excerpt from my **WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter super class**:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/static/**", "/login/*", "/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/site/admin*").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .usernameParameter("user-name")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/site/welcome", true)
                .loginProcessingUrl("/process-login")
                .failureUrl("/login?login_error=1")
            .and().logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
            .and().sessionManagement()
                .invalidSessionUrl("/login")
            .and().csrf()
            .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler);
}
```

My custom **AccessDeniedHandler** implementation:

```java
@Component
public class CustomAccessDeniedHandler implements AccessDeniedHandler {
    private static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(CustomAccessDeniedHandler.class);

    @Override
    public void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            AccessDeniedException accessDeniedException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        final Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (authentication != null) {
            LOG.warn(String.format("User [%s] attempted to access the protected URL [%s]!", authentication.getName(), request.getRequestURI()));
        }

        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/site/403");
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to check whether the CustomAccessDeniedHandler instance is created at all. Could be problem of recognizing the bean e.g. the bean out of scan path.

Comment: @StanislavL That is it! I have no idea why it doesn't inject the bean to the config class though. Other classes in the same package are injected without a problem. I tried to name the bean and inject it with a `@Qualifier`, but to no avail... I will try to create the bean manually using `@Bean` annotation, but I can't see any reason why it doesn't work as it is now... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to assign the autowired constructor parameter to a field! I am sorry for posting such a trivial problem here, but after I spent half a day looking for a solution, I was blind and I missed it...

```
public SpringSecurityConfiguration(
            AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler, ...) {
        this.accessDeniedHandler = accessDeniedHandler; // This line was missing.
        ...
}
```