# Need to manually re-authorize using OAuth2AuthorizationRequest not working

Tags: spring-security, authorization, spring-security-oauth2

I'm building a client application that need to be able to step-up a user in case the authentication level is not sufficient.
For this the resource server evaluates the access_token through introspection and returns a 401 with a WWW-Authenticate header back to the client.

The client implements a @ExceptionHandler to catch the 401 and should then do the necessary to do the re-authorization with the new authentication level.

Currently I'm trying to create an OAuth2AuthorizationRequest in which I add my additionalParameters.
However, the returned Oauth2AuthorizationRequest is null and hence I'm unable to obtain the right Oauth2AuthorizationRequest to authorize through the OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager.

In essence the process is the following:

- User accesses the client and is send out for authentication
- User performs basic operations using the client to a resource server
- User performs more critical action and resource server responds with 401
- Client gets redirected to Authorization server to re-authenticate (based on new authentication level specified in the authorization request)
- User re-authenticates and gets redirected to client app with new session
- Initial operation of user is re-attempted (now with the new session) to the resource server

I have developed most of my client application...
I'm just stuck at creating the right OAuth2AuthorizationRequest to redirect the user to my OIDC provider and have the session updated with the new session details (access_token, userinfo, id token).

```java
@PostMapping("/reauthenticate")
public String postAuthenticate(OAuth2AuthenticationToken authentication, @RequestParam("acr") String acr, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
              
CustomAuthorizationRequestResolver authorizationRequestResolver = new CustomAuthorizationRequestResolver(repo);
// Create a new OAuth2AuthorizationRequest using your custom AuthorizationRequestResolver
OAuth2AuthorizationRequest authorizationRequest = authorizationRequestResolver.resolve(request);
// Add the additionalQueryParam to the authorization request
authorizationRequest = authorizationRequestResolver.modifyRequest(authorizationRequest, "acr_values", acr);
   
OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient = authorizedClientManager.authorize( (OAuth2AuthorizeRequest) authorizationRequest );
                
return "index";
```

Comment: Fairly sure you should get a ‘403 - Forbidden’ not a ‘401 - Unauthorized’ because the user is authenticated but not allowed for the specific path. You will need intercept the 403 (probably in a filter or interceptor) do some logic (because some 403s may be genuine and acr will have rules) and respond with a redirect (http-302 with location header) that takes the browser to /reauthenticate?acr=asdf. This is going to be difficult.

Comment: The redirect should be implemented in a custom AccessDeniedHandler based on the built-in Spring version with overwrites. Start here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55690998/how-to-fix-overriding-of-default-accessdeniedhandler-accessdeniedhandlerimpl-i

Comment: Thanks for the comment. A 403 is not adequate, the 40A is better suited as it allows for the WWW-Authenticate headers.
IETF is working on that in an internet draft: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-ietf-oauth-step-up-authn-challenge/

I'm already able to intercept the 401 and to extract the acr values. But then I don't know how to trigger the re-authorize.
I did manage at some point to create an OAuth2AuthorizationRequest, but apparently Spring Security expects a OAuth2AuthorizeRequest to call the authorize() method... and I have no clue how to transpose between the 2...

Comment: Trigger the reauth by redirecting. If you have the httpresponse available at the place you intercept the 401/3 you should be able to do a httpresponse.sendRedirect(“/reauthenticate?acr=asdf”). The state of the httpresponse at the point of interception might be a problem (ie committed) so you may need to intercept earlier, ie while doing authn/z with a custom security filter

Comment: I managed to get a redirect to the local authorization endpoint...
Adding the query param does not automatically adds it as parameter to the authorization reuqest. I have to modify my CustomAuthorizationRequestResolver to extract the parameters from the originl request before the OAuth2AuthorizationRequest is created...

Comment: `@Override
public OAuth2AuthorizationRequest resolve(HttpServletRequest request) {
        Map<String, String[]> params = request.getParameterMap();
        String acr = null;

        OAuth2AuthorizationRequest req = defaultResolver.resolve(request);

        if (req != null) {
            if (params.containsKey("acr_values")) {
                acr = params.get("acr_values")[0];
                req = modifyRequest(req, "acr_values", acr);
            }
            req = customizeAuthorizationRequest(req);
        }
        return req;
    }`